# Show two MySQL column as key and value in JSON format

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

I want to show this MySQL table data in JSON object format with *_key* column as **key** and *_value* column as **value**.
[image: mysql table data]

How can I do this with PDO in PHP?

I tried like this:

```
$info_arr = array();

while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    $info_arr[] = $row;
echo json_encode($info_arr);
```

But this gives me like this:

```
[
{
    "_key": "app_name",
    "_value": "Mathology"
},
{
    "_key": "app_package",
    "_value": "com.shovon.mathology"
},
{
    "_key": "app_version",
    "_value": "1.0"
},
{
    "_key": "app_icon",
    "_value": "com.shovon.mathology"
}
]
```

But I want to get result like this:

```
[
 {
     "app_name": "Mathology",
     "app_package": "com.shovon.mathology",
     "app_version": "1.0",
     "app_icon": "com.shovon.mathology"
 }
]
```

Comment: `$info_arr[$row['_key']] = $row['_value'];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo json_encode($result->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR));
```

Output:

```
{
    "app_name": "Mathology",
    "app_package": "com.shovon.mathology",
    "app_version": "1.0",
    "app_icon": "com.shovon.mathology"
}
```

I don't know why would you want to put a single object in a JSON array. My solution outputs just the object. If you want to wrap it in an array then just put it inside of `[]` before sending to `json_encode()`

```
echo json_encode([$result->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR)]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually I  will use multiple object that's why i used array. @dharman